# Notificaciones en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal, estoy intentando implementar un sistema de notifiaciones en mi aplicacion web, solo que no se como empezar, he estado googleando, esperando a encontrar una respuesta.

tengo una tabla en `MySQL` que tiene los siguientes campos:

id (PK) 
du_id (FK) 
nombre 
email 
comentarios 
cv 
visto.

quiero que al momento en que se haga el insert a la base de datos con esos datos, se le mande una notificacion al dueño de `du_id` como algo de nueva alerta y el numero de notificaciones pendientes de ver.

espero alguien me pueda ayudar, y si me pueden prporcionar un codigo, estaria muy agradecido

Busco un codigo que me realice algo asi [image: Algo asi]

Comment: ¿Podrías definir qué estás entendiendo por "notificación" en este caso? Y, de lo que estuviste googleando, ¿qué fue lo que encontraste, por qué no te sirvió y qué faltaría para cumplir tu objetivo que no encontraste en la web?

Comment: claro @Mariano, pondre una imagen de que es lo que quiero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien compañero, dijiste que no sabes como empezar, ¿Verdad? Bueno, esto a veces sucede cuando la experiencia requerida del objetivo supera los conocimientos actuales. Sin embargo, sabe la comunidad en general, todo aquel programador que ésta sensación es bien conocida cuando te dedicas a programar, ya que con el paso del tiempo quieres crear cosas mas grandes y vas aprendiendo mas y mas, y cada vez mas complejo todo. Pero tranquilo, todo se llega a controlar con el tiempo y práctica.Te intentaré ayudarte como lo haría yo ya que he sido capaz de imaginarlo en mi cabeza como para mi propio proyecto web. ¿Cómo implementarlo?

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma y es pensando en el "recorrido" que realizaria ese servicio.
Lo primero es dividir en tantos procesos como puedas el objetivo complejo y hacerlo facil.

1º creas un formulario en tu panel de administración

a)En este panel creas una sección donde habrá un formulario para crear notificaciones. Esto implica un formulario con 

`Campo de texto para tu notificación "INPUT TEXT", 
campo para referencia id cliente "INPUT NUMBER",`

b)Rellenas los 2 datos (el mensaje y el ID del cliente)

c) Después enviarlo a la logica que controla los datos del formulario.

2º Llegan los datos del formulario al controlador (logica)

a)Primero antes de nada debemos crear la tabla donde almacenar los datos de la notificación, es decir,
`notificaciones_usuarios`
En esta tabla vamos a tener:

`id - (incremental unica) para evitar repetir entradas en la base de datos
texto (EL FORMULARIO)
id_user (EL FORMULARIO) Clave foranea a la tabla usuarios
fecha - date() o dia de creación
leer (boolean) 1 leido | 0 no leido`

b) Ahora si con los datos que viene  del formulario enviado, los guardamos en esta tabla y la logica que deberiamos hacer para guardarlos sería.

`"id" de la notificación será autoincremental desde 1 hasta 99999... 
"texto" será el que escribamos en el formulario de administración Input
"id_user" será el id del cliente del formulario de administración Input
"fecha" será la fecha del dia que creamos el mensaje y lo enviamos date()
'leer' es un booleano que por defecto estará en "0" (no leido) y "1" (leido).`

3º Las vistas del cliente desde su panel de usuario (registrado y logeado)
Puedes colocar esto donde quieras, como dices arriba en 1 icono, en la barra de navegación puedes hacer la logica de:

*Consulta a la base de datos:

`{Busca los mensajes en la tabla "notificaicones_usuarios" con el parametro de "leer en 0" y con la "id de usuario logeado".}`

Y esta consulta le haces el tipico count(QUERY) y cuentas cuantas entradas con esos parametros existen o has obtenido con esos parametros.
Es decir, cuantos mensajes sin leer tiene el cliente concreto.
Y por tanto pintas el numerito en el icono. de vistas del cliente.

---

Bueno hasta aquí sería lo que tu deseas, y hasta aquí te ofrezco ya que esta forma de "ayudar" se que igual algunos no estarán de acuerdo, ya que es "duro/arduo" leer así la lógica, pero no se olviden que el que la va a leer es el interesado. Estando en su lugar hace 1 año y pico...me hubiera venido bien que me explicaran algo así cuando tenia yo mis dudas complejas siendo un principiante. Y por ello, te ayudo hasta donde preguntas de manera directa a tu solución.

Darle mas personalización a lo que pides me pareceria obvio..pero no necesario en tu caso, con comprender esta lógica y lograrlo por ti mismo...será un gran paso y avance para ti. Ánimo!

Espero que ayude al señor Cesar Gutierrez Davalos ;D

PD: La razón de no realizar el código es que como bien dijiste, no sabías como empezar, y aquí estamos para ayudar a solventar una duda o problema, pero no para realizar todo el codigo de otro desde 0, con todos los respetos a tu pregunta, te entiendo y te doy una solución a como empezar a picar el codigo. Simplemente, ahora que tienes una lógica para empezar a programar, intenta realizarlo y si tienes problemas de código te invito a volver a preguntar en esta comunidad aportando lo ya realizado por ti y así poder encontrar el fallo/duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Minerillo, de hecho empece a buscar la forma con una funcion y en ella haciendo un `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postula WHERE id = $id AND seen = 0"` solo que al momento de abrir alguna notificacion, ¿tendria que usar ajax para poner seen en 1?

Comment: `$mensajes = SELECT * FROM notificaciones_users WHERE leer == 0 && user == $idUsuario ORDER BY fecha DESC` Y ahora `numNotificacionesUser = count($mensajes)` Obteniendo asi Todos los mensajes del usuario id concreta que no esten leidos y por orden de fecha descendente :). Ya puedes jugar con los query o consulta en funcion de tu lógica pero la idea es sacar sacar ya lo que quieras =)

Comment: Gracias por responderme, he hecho una funcion o al menos eso cre jaja `function obtener_notificaciones($conexion, $us){
 $notu = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postula WHERE du_id = '".$_POST['id']."' AND seen = 0");
 $notu = $resultado->fetchAll();
 return ($notu);
 print_r($notu);
}` es solo que como hago para imprimir el return o la funcion en un div `<li><a href="notificaciones.html"> Notificaciones (5)</a></li>`

Comment: ah la variable `$us` la obtengo de la otra funcion `function comprobarSession(){
 if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
  header('Location: ' .  RUTA . '/login.php');
 }
 else {
  $us = $_SESSION['usuario'];
 }
}`

Comment: Pues depende del codigo que uses. Si es PHP a pelo, entonces será en el propio archivo donde tienes el botoncito de notificaciones, ahí deberas ejecutar tu función y obtener el numerito de mensajes.
$numNotificaciones = function($conexion, $us);
Y si está bien creada la función y te regresa en el return tu numerito, deberia guardarse en esa variable.
"$VAR" = "TU FUNCION()"

Comment: Ok, creo tener una idea de como debo hacerlo. muchas gracias!

Comment: si mal no entendi, crees que estoy poniendo el codigo en el mismo archivo que las etiquetas html? Si es asi, no, tengo un fichero exclusivo para las funciones y otro para las etiquetas, en este caso es functions.php y el otro es lateral.php, como puedo llamar la funcion desde lateral.php? Lo trate de hacer asi: en el fichero lateral.php `<?php $conteo = obtener_notificaciones ($conexion); ?>` pero me tira error

Comment: Lees obre las funciones en PHP
`require() / include(); /require_once() / include_once()`

Con ellas llamas a otros archivos php y "los incluyes" o defines que requieren de ciertas funciones etc etc. Tocale a ese tema

En tu caso igual para probarlo, con un simple include('functions.php') y esto hará que en tu archivo se incluya el php de functions y podrás utilizar las funciones que hay ahí =) Pero te recomiendo que leas sobre su uso ya que difiere en unos casos y en otros.

Answer (score 0):

No sé cómo es como envías datos a tu frontend, pero suponiendo que lo haces mediante request, tienes que hacer con jQuery o el framework que uses un get a tu servidor, enviado como parámetros el id del usuario, y que te devuelva como respuesta el número de mensajes que tiene, y mostrarlo

No te puedo escribir un código porque no sé qué usas, la idea es esa, tienes que buscar más ejemplos.

Comment: no que mande emails, lo de emails es solo para tener una manera de contactar a la persona que envia el mensaje, puse una imagen para una idea que es lo que busco

Comment: El concepto es el mismo, tendrías que tener un demonio mirando tu tabla, por ejemplo cada segundo o dos, desde tu frontend para que actualice los mensajes, si es que tiene.

Comment: alguna idea de como?

Comment: No se como es  como envías datos a tu frontend, pero suponiendo que lo haces mediante request, tienes que hacer con jquery o el framework que uses un get a tu servidor, enviado como parámetros el id del usuario y que te devuelva como respuesta el numero de mensajes que tiene y mostrarlo, no te puedo escribir un código porque no se que usas, la idea es esa, tienes que buscar mas ejemplos, no esperes que te den todo resuelto.

Comment: @Nicolás edité tu pregunta porque era más cercana a un comentario... y paradójicamente, tu comentario estaba más cercano a una respuesta... Respecto a eso, quizás no convenga en esta etapa complicarlo con una llamada por AJAX. Quizás con mostrar el número como resultado en la página sea un primer paso más sencillo (y luego ver de que sean en tiempo real)... Además, se podría agregar alguna idea de cómo gestionar la base para obtener la cantidad de eventos "no leídos".

Comment: Gracias Mariano, soy nuevo y por ayudar estoy haciendo todo un revoltijo.