# Update con PHP y PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy haciendo un `UPDATE` con `PDO`, anteriormente funcionaba, pero ahora por alguna extraña razon no funcion y no logro encontrar el error

Este es el `BackEnd`:

```
<?php session_start();

require 'extras/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

comprobarSession();

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $id = limpiarDatos($_POST['id']);
        $nombre = limpiarDatos($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellidos = limpiarDatos($_POST['apellidos']);
        $profesion = limpiarDatos($_POST['profesion']);
        $ciudad = limpiarDatos($_POST['ciudad']);
        $puesto = limpiarDatos($_POST['puesto']);
        $empresa = limpiarDatos($_POST['empresa']);
        $responsabilidades = limpiarDatos($_POST['responsabilidades']);
        $habilidades = limpiarDatos($_POST['habilidades']);
        $carrera = limpiarDatos($_POST['carrera']);
        $universidad = limpiarDatos($_POST['universidad']);
        $extra = limpiarDatos($_POST['extra']);
        $thumb_guardada = $_POST['thumb-guardada'];
        $thumb = $_FILES['thumb'];
        $cv_guardado = $_POST['curriculum-guardado'];
        $cv = $_FILES['curriculum'];

        if (empty($thumb['name'])) {
            $thumb = $thumb_guardada;
        } else {
            $archivo_subido = 'images/' . $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);
            $thumb = $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
        }

        if (empty($cv['name'])) {
            $cv = $cv_guardado;
        } else {
            $dir_subido = 'curriculum/';
            $cv_subido = $dir_subido . basename($_FILES['curriculum']['name']);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['curriculum']['tmp_name'], $cv_subido);
            $cv = $_FILES['curriculum']['name'];
        }

        $errores = '';

        if (empty($nombre) or empty($apellidos)) {
        $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
        } else {
            try {
                $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=empleos', 'root', '');
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $statement = $conexion->prepare(
        'UPDATE userslog
        SET
        nombre = :nombre,
        apellidos = :apellidos,
        profesion = :profesion,
        ciudad = :ciudad,
        puesto = :puesto,
        empresa = :empresa,
        responsabilidades = :responsabilidades,
        habilidades = :habilidades,
        carrera = :carrera,
        universidad = :universidad,
        extra = :extra,
        thumb = :thumb,
        cv = :curriculum
        WHERE id = :id'
      );

            if (!empty($errores)) {

                $statement->execute(array(
                    ':id' => $id,
                    ':nombre' => $nombre,
                    ':apellidos' => $apellidos,
                    ':profesion' => $profesion,
                    ':ciudad' => $ciudad,
                    ':puesto' => $puesto,
                    ':empresa' => $empresa,
                    ':responsabilidades' => $responsabilidades,
                    ':habilidades' => $habilidades,
                    ':carrera' => $carrera,
                    ':universidad' => $universidad,
                    ':extra' => $extra,
                    ':curriculum' => $cv,
                    ':thumb' => $thumb
                ));
        header('Location: empleos.php');
        die();
            }
        }
}


require "views/perfil.php";
```

y este es el `FrontEnd`:

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="perfil.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][0])  ?>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre(s)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][1])  ?>" placeholder="Nombre(s)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Apellidos</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos"  value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][2])  ?>" placeholder="Apellidos">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profesion</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profesion"  value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][3])  ?>" placeholder="Profesion">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Ciudad de recidensia</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ciudad"  value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][4])  ?>" placeholder="Ciudad de recidensia">
  </div>
  <hr>
<h4>Experiencia profesional</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Puesto</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="puesto"  value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][5])  ?>" placeholder="Puesto">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Empresa</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empresa"  value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][6])  ?>" placeholder="Nombre de la empresa">
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Responsabilidades</label>
    <textarea name=responsabilidades rows="8" cols=" 80" placeholder="Responsabilidades"><?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][7])  ?></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Habilidades</label>
    <textarea name="habilidades" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Responsabilidades"><?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][8])  ?></textarea>
  </div>
  <hr>
<h4>Formacion profesional</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre de la carrera</label>
    <input type="text" name="carrera"  value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][9])  ?>"  placeholder="Nombre de la carrera" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre de la universidad</label>
    <input type="text" name="universidad"  value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][10])  ?>" placeholder="Nombre de la universidad" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <hr>
<h4>Informacion adicional</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Habilidades</label>
    <textarea name="extra" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Habilidades"><?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][11])  ?></textarea>
  </div>
<hr>
<h4>Personaliza</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>CV</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="curriculum" placeholder="Sube tu CV">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="curriculum-guardado" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][14])  ?>" placeholder="Sube tu CV">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Foto de perfil</label>
    <input type="file" name="thumb" class="form-control" placeholder="Sube tu foto de perfil">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="thumb-guardada" class="form-control" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][15])  ?>" placeholder="Sube tu foto de perfil">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-t-primary">Actualizar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

y aunque tengo el `header('Location')` lo ignora y no hace ninguna redireccion, de igual manera si quito valores del `Execute` por obvias razones quitandole valores del `Execute`deberia fallar, pero no lo hace

Comment: @Xerif no me da ningun error, simplemente hace como si hiciera el update, pero no lo hace

Comment: Revisa el log o activa el reporte de errores para intentar saber que esta pasando. Es raro que no te indique nada. Tambien te puedes ayudar de http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php para ver si hay algun error con la consulta.

Comment: en cuanto a mi ignorancia... ¿Como reviso el log o activo el reporte de errores? https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmvS5ucAncFGhRPnwUSQAU1AtBFf ese es el enlace de mi codigo, espero le puedas echar un vistazo

Comment: pon esto al principio del script :  **error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');**

Comment: @Xerif he encontrado el error, aunque es algo extraño esta en el `if (!empty($errores)) {`

Comment: @Xerif disculpa, me podrias de casualidad ayudar con esta duda que tengo tambien? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75801/notificaciones-en-php/75807?noredirect=1#comment139421_75807

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes un error de sintaxis, deberías cambiar la linea por esta, no revise todo el lenguaje, fue lo que vi a simple vista.

```
comprobarSession();//mal
comprobarSession(){//bien
```

Comment: comprobarSession(); tiene toda la pinta de que es una función declarada anteriormente. en todo caso tambien le faltaria el **function**.  function nombre_funcion(){}

Comment: claro, es una funcion, pero lo que hace la funcion es solo para saber si ya hay una sesion iniciada, y si la hay no te permite entrar a registro o login

Comment: Perdón, es que esta todo mal identado, es difícil de analizar, ya que puede que el error este en otro archivo.

Comment: ¿Que pasa con los campos 'thumb-guardada' y 'curriculum-guardado' que no están en tu update?